# Bootstrap submenu click event doesn't work with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav, submenu

I have the following Bootstrap submenu structure:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="submenu-open">
        <a href="http://google.com"><span class="dropdown-sub-toggle"></span>Some Text</a>
        <ul class="collapse dropdown-submenu">
            <li> 
                <a href="http://google.com">Some Text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The menu is collapsing when I click on span tag - it's an arrow from the right. I need to prepend some text to span tag when it's clicked, but I can't select it with jQuery - `$('.dropdown-sub-toggle').click(function({...}))` doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact the span is inside the <a> tag, thus clicking on the span triggers the click on the link. Do you need to be able to follow the link also ?

Comment: The link works separately and span just collapses the menu. It all works, but I can't select it with jQuery. P.S. the first level menu with identical structure works fine with jQuery.

Comment: Do you have a demo page somewhere ? Might be easier to debug with full scripts.

Comment: No I haven't launched it yet :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".submenu-open").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".dropdown-sub-toggle").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).prepend("Some Text");
});
```

This worked for me.

You could also add stopProgagation().

```
$(".dropdown-sub-toggle").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).prepend("Some Text");
});
```

To prevent event bubbling.

Can't see any other reasons why this wouldn't work.